# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'evaluate' with evaluating of loaded model in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, evaluate

```
# my save model function 
# saving and reloadinng the trained model 
import os 
def save_model(model,suffix = None):
    model_dir = os.path.join('./',datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%s"))
    model_path = model_dir + '-' + suffix + '.h5' # save format of the model 
    print('saving model to : ' + model_path + '...')
    model.save(model_path)
    return model_path
```

load model function :

```
def load_model(model_path):
    print('loading saved model from ' + model_path)
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path,custom_objects = {'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer},compile=False)
```

[image: after saving and loading the model there is no error]

```
loaded_1000_image_model.evaluate(val_data)
```

when I am trying to evaluate the loaded model then it's saying

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-1940330b6409> in <module>
----> 1 loaded_1000_image_model.evaluate(val_data)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'evaluate'
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is caused by a typo and therefore unlikely to positively contribute to this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `load_model` function needs to `return model`